# C# - Get dynamic URL Parameter on API call

Tags: c#, .net, parameter-passing, dotnet-httpclient

I'm building an movie API using C# where the user calls my endpoint and based on the id passed, my server calls the movie database API to get some details.

For example: if a user calls the "/movie/id" endpoint, the server gets that id and pass it to the movieDb.Get method.

My main issue is on retrieving that id the user passes in the URL when accessing my endpoint

This is what i've been trying:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/movie/{id}", (id) =>
{    
    object response = movieDb.Get($"/movie/{id}");
    return response;
});
```

and my class:

```
public class MovieDB{
public async Task<object> Get(string uri){
            try{
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{baseUrl}/{uri}? 
                                                                           {apiKey}");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseBody;
            }
            catch (Exception){
                throw;
            }
        }
```

}

When I access "http://localhost:port/movie/616037", I expect to see the movie database return to this movie, but I get:

> "connection was refused by the localhost".

If I force and id like

```
string id = "616037"
```

and then call this method sending the correct endpoint on movie database API, then it returns this movie details
e.g.

```
movieDB.Get($"/movie/{id}")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: updated the question. tell me if it isn't clear yet

Comment: @GuilhermeKenzo It's unfortunately still unclear what the problem is in the first two code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify parameter. Because without specifying id is HttpContext
[image]

Your code must look like this

```
app.MapGet("/movie/{id}", (int id) =>{
...
}
```